# How to avoid symbolic evaluation in functions passed as a parameter to a Mathematica function?

Tags: functions

I am new to Mathematica, I am trying to implement Newton's method to find zeros of functions, the code works perfectly in a routine, but when I use `Module` to define it as a function, the output of `Print [x]` is a symbolic evaluation instead of a numeric one (I need it to evaluate the calculations). I have not found related examples in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated. The code is the following:

```
newtonMethod[x0_,f_,\[Epsilon]_, M_]:=Module[{},
x=x0;
u[z_]:=z-(f[z]/f'[z]) ;
For[n=0,n<M, n++, 
Print[x];
If[Abs[x-u[x]]<\[Epsilon],Print["The zero is:", u[x]] Break[]];
x=u[x];
] 
]

q[z_]:= z^3-Sinh[z]+4z^2+6z+9;    (*The function we want to find the zeros*)
newtonMethod[5.,q[z],0.001,15]
```

The code works without the `Module` function:

```
Clear[z];
f[z_]:= z^3-Sinh[z]+4z^2+6z+9
\[Epsilon]=0.001;
 M=10;
x=5.;
u[z_]:=z-(f[z]/f'[z]) ;
For[n=0,n<M, n++, 
Print[x];
If[Abs[x-u[x]]<\[Epsilon],Print["The zero is:", u[x]] Break[]];
x=u[x];
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your local variables in the `Module` spec, and there are other issues like you're passing in `q[z]` instead of the function `q`:

```
newtonMethod[x0_, f_, ϵ_, M_] := Module[{x = x0, u, n},
  u[z_] := z - (f[z]/f'[z]);
  For[n = 0, n < M, n++, Print[x];
   If[Abs[x - u[x]] < ϵ, Print["The zero is:", u[x]]; 
    Break[], x = u[x]];
   ]]

(*The function we want to find the zeros*)
q[z_] := z^3 - Sinh[z] + 4 z^2 + 6 z + 9;

newtonMethod[5., q, 0.001, 15]

(*... The zero is:7.11306 *)
```

I would recommend using `FixedPoint`, `FixedPointList`, `NestWhile`, or `NestWhileList` to do Newton's method instead of a `For` loop.

```
newtonMethod2[x0_, f_, ϵ_, M_] := Module[{next},
  NestWhileList[next = # - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, 
   Abs[# - next] < ϵ &, M]]

(*The function we want to find the zeros*)
q[z_] := z^3 - Sinh[z] + 4 z^2 + 6 z + 9;

newtonMethod2[5., q, 0.001, 15]

(* {5., 0.943651, -0.275642, -2.92536, 6.30229, 8.18339, 7.57969, 
7.22935, 7.12189, 7.11312, 7.11306, 7.11306, 7.11306, 7.11306, 7.11306} *)
```

Comment: Note for functions where you can't get the derivative easily, you can either calculate the limit yourself or instead use: [`ResourceFunction["NDerivative"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NDerivative)

Comment: In this case with NestWhileList [], the M is no longer the number of iterations, it's the number of zeros, right?

Comment: @Sjang the M is the maximum number of iterations.

Comment: Sure, I mean the iterations of the sequence in the method, I got it, thank you very much.

Comment: @flinty: can the second approach be extended for a system of equations?

Comment: @Moo the multidimensional Newton's method is a bit different, and involves partial derivatives, but basically yes.